# facebook likebox no posts just checkins

Tags: facebook

We are having a problem with our newsfeed - it is essentially a likebox plugin to save having to update both the website and our facebook page.

Using an iframe, the facebook page populates the newsfeed. If the viewer of the website is not logged into facebook everything is working correctly.

HOWEVER - if the person is logged into facebook (as most people seem to be!) none of the posts on the facebook page are feeding through to the website and it is simply showing the latest check in.

Is this a common bug? I am using the code directly from the facebook developers page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

I have tried using the XFBML version as opposed to the iframe but getting the same result.

Does anyone know of a way around this!? Its killing me!

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following attribute:

`force_wall="true"`

to your iframe.  it was added a couple of months ago - see here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ and scroll down to attributes.

Comment: it's taken me about 2 hours of googling to find this. only when i started typing the question into stackoverflow did it come up! this must apply to pages which are pre a certain date. it still happens using up to date code (19 feb 14) for the like-box. try https://www.facebook.com/pages/Second-Sight-Opticians-wwwsecondsightopticianscom/154296354589272

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug in Facebook and it was fixed in July 2011.

Refer to this post
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16656#c41

you have to add

```
force_wall="true"
```

So for example, if you are using iframe version, you can add it at the end of src like below.

```
<iframe src="http:INSERT YOUR WEBSITE HERE;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=427&amp;force_wall=true"
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;
width:292px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```